# How to start failed network.service in debian 9

Tags: linux-networking

```
> /etc/init.d/networking status
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-27 11:51:25 AEDT; 11s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 3877 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3873 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 3877 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery ifup[3877]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery ifup[3877]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery ifup[3877]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery ifup[3877]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery ifup[3877]: exiting.
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery ifup[3877]: ifup: failed to bring up eth1
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 27 11:51:25 Bakery systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[root@Bakery][18.50.48-4.5][][3][~]
> service networking restart
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: ' networking.service

Comment: If you still need help show us both eth0 and eth1 : `ifconfig -a`

Comment: Systems administration lesson 1: read your logs. You only get a snippet from `systemctl status`

Comment: Systems administration lesson 2: read the messages. `systemctl status` tells you how to implement lesson 1

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` directory and if there are files in there
try to comment out the line (put # in front):

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
```

in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Also, depending the setup you use it would be helpful to post the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` if you need any further support.

The ideea here is to minimize your config file content untill you get to the part that prevents your networking service from starting...

Comment: Hi, thanks,Networking.service is failed but my lan ETH0 and all other network communication are working fine but i just need to remove this "failed error" when we run STATUS command.                                                    
"interfaces" is as below

auto lo<br/>iface lo inet loopback<br/>auto eth0<br/>allow-hotplug<br/>eth0<br/>iface eth0<br/>inet dhcp<br/>auto wlan0<br/>allow-hotplug wlan0<br/>iface wlan0 inet static<br/>address 10.123.45.199<br/>netmask 255.255.255.0<br/>wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf<br/>auto eth1<br/>allow-hotplug eth1<br/>iface eth1 inet dhcp